# Finger landing order for D#m chord (and similar)

Tags: guitar, chords, fingering

Which one is a faster finger landing order for this and similars chords:

4-3-2-1 or 3-4-2-1 (4 is a pinky finger).

I play 3-4-2-1(somehow faster for me)

[image: http://img818.imageshack.us/img818/2979/capturebod.jpg]

Comment: I am curious as to why you originally called this an "advanced" chord. It is merely a *diatonic triad*. That is the simplest kind of chord that exists.

Comment: @WheatWilliams because it uses all four fingers, perhaps?

Comment: Or because it's not in first position and uses no open strings?

Answer (score 7):

With experience and practice, you won't think about the order in which you place fingers for a chord like this. You'd place all your fingers at the same time.

In the meantime, I would tend towards 1-2-3-4 -- your stronger first two fingers can anchor the hand before you place the other two.

Comment: I just watched what I do and while they are very close in timing, it looks like I do 1 and 4 slightly before 2 and 3. I agree though, that you just fire them all down at what feels like the same time.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things you should be aware of when you're learning chords. The first one relates to your question but the two other are also extremely important so I just had to write them:

- **Changing to the chord midair:** For faster chord changes, you won't have time to place your fingers individually. You have got to be able to place your fingers in the right position **before** they touch the fretboard. This will take some practice but it will extremely improve your technique.
- **Minimal pressure on the strings:** Take your guitar, and make a D chord. Put a lot of pressure onto the strings and strum the chord. Now put as little pressure as possible before the strings begin to buzz, and strum the chord again. Hopefully, you should be able to tell the difference.
- **Intonation:** Take your guitar and put your first finger on the 5th fret of the G string. Now bend the string a little bit and you'll be able to hear the tone difference. You do not want to do this with your chords. Make sure that your fingers are not bending the strings at all (Not even by an eighth of a tone).